# I have a problem with annotate. I want to add a subset counter column, but it doesn't get added

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
class ProductGroupInstanceInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model=ProductGroup 

@admin.register(ProductGroup)
class ProductGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('group_title','is_active','group_parents','slug','register_date','update_date',)
    list_filter=('group_title','group_parents',)
    search_fields=('group_title',)
    ordering=('group_title','group_title',)
    inlines=[ProductGroupInstanceInlineAdmin]
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args , **kwargs):
        qs=super(ProductGroupAdmin,self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs)
        qs=qs.annotate(sub_group = Count('groups'))
        return qs
    
    def count_sub_group(self,obj):
        return obj.sub_group
```

I tried to add an extra column using the annotate method, which counts the subsets of my groups, but this additional column does not appear at all.